# ORMLite Mapping reference Alias column

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I use the following code for my POCO: As you can see my property that is my reference is assigned an Alias.

```
    public class MasterItemAlias
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public MasterItem MasterItem { get; set; }           
    [Alias("MasterItem_id")]
    public int MasterItemId { get; set; } 

}
```

I use LoadSelect for my query but only the MasterItemID (int) is populated and not the Reference object MasterItem.

```
var res = Db.LoadSelect<Resources.Entities.MasterItemAlias>();
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [stand-alone repro on Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=0cd558e817f28f77b974c44c3e12ff6f&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a) I can run to see the issue.

Comment: https://gistlyn.com/?gist=0cd558e817f28f77b974c44c3e12ff6f&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a

Comment: Can you save the gist and send me a link to the new URL/gist, this is still the original gist & link.

Comment: @mythz https://gistlyn.com/?gist=0cd558e817f28f77b974c44c3e12ff6f&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a

Comment: This is the same link again? If you hit Save As (or Ctrl+s), it should ask you what new name you should use for your Gist and redirect you there, if it's not working for you, please post the code into a GitHub Gist and send me a link to it.

Comment: @mythz  https://gistlyn.com/?gist=e3e65a063dbf0c8e26a38a30e643c7e0&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a

Comment: @mythz  https://gist.github.com/fdtaljaard/e3e65a063dbf0c8e26a38a30e643c7e0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue with your example](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=e3e65a063dbf0c8e26a38a30e643c7e0&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a) is because the Foreign Key Id and Primary Key types don't match, it will work if you change `MasterItemId` to `long`, e.g:

```
public class MasterItem 
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}

db.CreateTable<MasterItem>();

public class MasterItemAlias
{
    [AutoIncrement] //missing as Id was not specified on Save below
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AliasCode { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    public MasterItem MasterItem { get; set; }           
    [Alias("MasterItem_id")]
    public long MasterItemId { get; set; } 
}

db.CreateTable<MasterItemAlias>();

var newMasterItem = new MasterItem {
    Code = "MI_CODE"
};
db.Save(newMasterItem);

var y = db.LoadSelect<MasterItemAlias>();
```

> Note: you only need `[AutoIncrement]` which also makes it the Primary Key

Comment: I had a similar problem with a List-reference.

Leaving out the ForeignKeyAttribute will result in LoadSelect looking for a property with the AliasAttribute name instead of the actual aliased property's name.

Is this by design?